# IBU rate of Sierra Nevada's "torpedo"?

Tags: hops, bitterness, all-grain

I am preparing to start a season of working up a solid, reasonably priced All grain American Ale on the brink of a high gravity beer.  Sierra Nevada's Torpedo balances sweet malt nicely against a hop construct that I am having a hard time figuring against other examples, Dogfishead 60 min +English examples like Young's Ramrod.  I've brewed many Barleywines where the bitterness seems to be through the roof until the malt checks in. Can someone clue me in on the IBUs versus base malt alone for this in between style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jamil sheds some light on possibly similar subject here: http://www.mrmalty.com/late_hopping.htm

Also, Lagunitas Undercover Investigation Shutdown Ale (described by them as an "oxymoronic Imperial Mild") might be of interest to you. If you can find it...

Comment: Thanks Joe.  The article was very informative, and I've been pushing my late additions for flavoring to match the style.

Answer (score 3):

From the website:
alcohol content 7.2% by volume
beginning gravity 17.3 Plato (~1.070 SG)
ending gravity 4.2 Plato (~1.017 SG)
bitterness units 65
malts Two-row Pale, & Crystal
yeast Ale Yeast
bittering hops Magnum
finishing hops Magnum & Crystal
dry hopping Magnum, Crystal & Citra

The values for gravity and IBU are measured in their lab, not estimated from a spreadsheet.  I would assume they post the measured values on the site.

There was a recipe in Zymurgy last summer.  I can't find the issue right now, but I'll post the recipe when I find it.